# How do I get the selected rowList on jqGrid Pager?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have to save the selection made by user on the grid. One of the things to save is the value selected from the rowList on the jqgrid pager. I have the onPaging: function(pgButton) method working but grid.getGridParam('rowNum') shows me the previous value not the selected value from rowList. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to do it. I right clicked on the rowList dropdown and did inspect element. I got the class name for it and then got the value as below.

var temp1 = $('.ui-pg-selbox').val();

To get the page # change I got it as below
var temp2 = $('.ui-pg-input').val();

Both of these were accessed inside onPaging: function(pgButton)